# How to put UIlabel on UIImageView programatically

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uilabel

I'm trying to put a `UIlabel` on a `UIImageView` which is in a `UIScrollView`. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Simply AddSubview the uilabel on your uiimageview

Comment: @IronManGill i have already added but it is not visible. Please let me know how can i ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

imageView is a UIView, so you can add subviews to it. 
also make sure you set the label with an appropriate frame

You can do:

```
UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,20)]; //or whatever size you need
[imageView addSubview:myLabel];
```

Comment: hi, Once i put UIImageview then it give error message. No known class method for selector' addSubview:'

Comment: if you are using a standard UIImageView and not a custom one this shuold work. make sure the selector is addSubview:label -note the capital letter..

Answer (score 0):

You can add it directly by dragging Label from to your storyboard/xib if you want it to e static. But if you want it to dynamically generate at runtime then you should add it by using

```
UILabel *yourlabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(YOUR COORDINATES)];
```

then you can add it to any of your view.For your imageview you can add it as

```
[imageview addSubview:yourlabel];
```

Often you may require to remove it from that view if not needed. You can similarly call removeFromSuperView also.
Hope this works :)

Comment: One quick note regarding this: Last I checked, it's not possible to add a subview to a UIImageView **in Interface Builder**. It's completely possible, as you've described, in code, and you can add subviews to many view types in IB - but not UIImageViews.